# If Amazon S3 buckets are supposed to be "globally unique" across the whole AWS cloud, how do I have a bucket named "todo"?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I created a bucket in Amazon S3 and named it "todo", and the bucket was created successfully with no errors. There is absolutely no way that no one else has used that bucket name, so if buckets are supposed to be globally unique, how did this happen?

Comment: Apparently you were lucky? :P it's globally unique indeed

Comment: yeah i guess i was! although you might argue i was actually unlucky given how much confusion this caused me...

Answer (score 1):

I tried creating a bucket with the name **todo** and got an exception as expected. I suppose you were the 1st to name a bucket with that name.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException {
        final String USAGE = "\n" +
                "Usage:\n" +
                "    <bucketName> \n\n" +
                "Where:\n" +
                "    bucketName - the name of the bucket to create. The bucket name must be unique, or an error occurs.\n\n" ;

      //  if (args.length != 1) {
      //      System.out.println(USAGE);
      //      System.exit(1);
      // }

        String bucketName = "todo"; //args[0];
        System.out.format("Creating a bucket named %s\n",
                bucketName);

        Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
        S3Client s3 = S3Client.builder()
                .region(region)
                .build();

        createBucket (s3, bucketName);
        s3.close();
    }

    // snippet-start:[s3.java2.create_bucket_waiters.main]
    public static void createBucket( S3Client s3Client, String bucketName) {

        try {
            S3Waiter s3Waiter = s3Client.waiter();
            CreateBucketRequest bucketRequest = CreateBucketRequest.builder()
                    .bucket(bucketName)
                    .build();

            s3Client.createBucket(bucketRequest);
            HeadBucketRequest bucketRequestWait = HeadBucketRequest.builder()
                    .bucket(bucketName)
                    .build();

            // Wait until the bucket is created and print out the response.
            WaiterResponse<HeadBucketResponse> waiterResponse = s3Waiter.waitUntilBucketExists(bucketRequestWait);
            waiterResponse.matched().response().ifPresent(System.out::println);
            System.out.println(bucketName +" is ready");

        } catch (S3Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
```